# Using USB or serial port by native client/ppapi?

Tags: file, dll, serial-port, google-nativeclient

Now, I have a DLL file  that has the function of the serial port operation,

I don't know that I can call the file and serial port operation by native client/ppapi .

Answer (score 2):

From a Chrome App you can use the chrome.serial Javascript API to talk to serial devices, if you've requested permission in your application manifest.
https://developer.chrome.com/apps/serial

There isn't currently a PPAPI serial interface available to Native Client modules, so you'd have to proxy serial output / events to the NaCl module from JavaScript via postMessage.

This isn't available currently on general web pages, though a page can communicate with an app / extension as a bridge. So depending on your application, you might be able to have an "Add Serial Capabilities" button that triggers an app install at the point a user is ready to grant serial access.

File access has similar limitations, although there are PPAPI interfaces to manipulate file/directory references from JavaScript, once the user has opted in. Similarly a normal page doesn't have direct access. Pages and Apps/Extensions of course do have isolated persistent storage associated with the origin of the page, which often is a better choice than file access anyway.

Comment: thark you ver much,Chrome and firefox will not support NPAPI technology, I have a project need to be compatible with the mainstream browsers, I known that Native Client can achieve this requirement by internet.But the project also has the function of the serial port operation, so I don't know how to use native client finish the requirment?

Comment: You will need to use postMessage / handleMessage to communicate serial data to/from JavaScript, which has access to the chrome.serial api, which can then read/write the data to the serial port.

Unsure if Firefox has an equivalent API.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do this from an app/extension, or from the web?

From an extension you should be able to use [native messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) to communicate with external applications. From the web there ins't anything available yet (thought your web site could talk to an extension), but there are early explorations in the standards space to expose device capabilities to the web.

Comment: thark you ver much,Chrome and firefox will not support NPAPI technology, I have a project need to be compatible with the mainstream browsers, I known that Native Client can achieve this requirement by internet.But  the  project also has the function of the serial port operation, so I don't know how to use native client finish the requirment?